# I'm trying to translate or create similar code using RaphaelJS.

Tags: css, svg, raphael

I'm trying to translate or create similar code using RaphaelJS. If you look at the code, you will see that I'm trying to create an animated path using css and js.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FC2qiZumzgjKSJOs6Zm5?p=info

```
var spinner = function() {
this.transition = function() {
var path = document.querySelector('#spinner-wrapper .spinner #main-path');
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
path.style.strokeDasharray = '205.951';
path.style.strokeDashoffset = 430;
path.getBoundingClientRect();
path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 3s linear';
};

this.startInterval = function(immediate,time) {
if(immediate){
  setTimeout(transition,0);
}
this.interval = setInterval(function() {
  transition();
}, time);
return this.interval;
};

this.start = function() {
clearInterval(this.interval);
startInterval(true,2700);
};

this.stop = function() {
clearInterval(this.interval);
startInterval(false,0);
};

return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using jQuery and RaphaelJS. It still doesn't work in IE browsers for some reasons. Maybe you can figure this out.

http://jsfiddle.net/shojib/ceqs86go/

```
var paper = new Raphael('canvas');
var pathString = "M16.47,19.938c7-0.5,4.5-10.5-2-7c-7,3.5,1,13,7.5,10 c13.5-7-9.5-27-16-6.5c-4.5,16,22,17,26,2c4.5-15.5-15-22.5-25-11.5c-5.5,6.5-9,16-0.5,21.5c4,2.5,15,6,19,2.5 c-3-3.5-7.5-8-9.5-10.5";


var pattern2 = paper.path(pathString); 
pattern2.attr({fill: 'none',stroke: '#ffffff',"stroke-miterlimit": '10','stroke-opacity': '1'}); 

var pattern1 = paper.path(pathString); 
pattern1.attr({fill: 'none',stroke: '#CD5300',"stroke-miterlimit": '10','stroke-opacity': '1'}); 

$(pattern1.node).css({
'stroke-dasharray': '210.991px',
'stroke-dashoffset': '430px'
});

$(pattern1.node).animate({
'stroke-dashoffset': '0'
},{
duration: 3000,
easing: 'linear'
});
```

Comment: Doesnt work in Chrome either. Do you really need to use jquery in this case as well (it always feels clunky accessing .node unless really required) ? It may depend a bit on which IE version you need, and whether it supports this particular animation.